# Quickblox: Message Delivered and Read Status

Tags: javascript, chat, message, quickblox

I have implemented quickblox chat in my web application. Now I want to show status of my messages as `delivered` in case when they are just sent to user and as `read` when they have seen the message.

In your Javascript SDK I have found two functions `QB.chat.sendDeliveredMessage` and `QB.chat.sendReadMessage` but every time I call this function as :

```
QB.chat.sendDeliveredMessage(
    QBChatHelpers.getJID(chatUser.id),
    "5600f885a28f9ac7e801048c"    //this is just a sample msg-id
);
```

It calls ajax with `POST` request over url `http://chat.quickblox.com:8080/` while chat is running over `http://chat.quickblox.com:5280/`. 
Also within library, I changed the port to 5280 in place of 8080 so that it can call url with port `8080` and it calls `http://chat.quickblox.com:5280/` which then gives error code `405: Invalid Hostname`.

Please let me know what's wrong am I doing while calling this function. If further information is required then do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on this feature, in the new version of QuickBlox JS SDK messages will be sent with the **markable** status.
**sendDeliveredStatus**(params)-will be sent automatically after receiving a message with **markable** status, which will signalize via the function of Listener *QB.chat.onDeliveredStatusListener(messageId, dialogId, userId)*;

**sendReadStatus(params)**-will be possible to send it according to an event (for example, you set up a processor, which will notice that a message has already appeared on yours monitor, after receiving a message with **markable** status, which will signalize via the function of Listener *QB.chat.onReadStatusListener(messageId, dialogId, userId)*;)

parameters for status sending:

```
params = {
    messageId: messageId,
    userId: userId,
    dialogId: dialogId
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Sabina, I was also able to achieve above using QB's new JS SDK and functions like `QB.chat.sendDeliveredMessage` and `QB.chat.sendReadMessage`, which send a message and getting the type of message within onMessage listener showing respective status accordingly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, this page helped me a lot.

When a message is sent could be 2 options:

- A. You are the sender and another user is the addressee: YOU --> ANOTHER-USER
- B. You are the addressee and another user is the sender: ANOTHER-USER --> YOU

**OPTION A:**

1. Send your message to the addressee with "markable=1" flag.
   For example:

   ```
     var params = {
       chat_dialog_id: "56b20540f583bb7bcb00rrr6",
       message: msg),
       send_to_chat: 1,
       markable: 1,
       extension: {
         save_to_history: 1
       }
     };

     // SEND THE MESSAGE
     QB.chat.message.create(params, function (err, res) {});
   ```
2. Add QB listener to be trigger after the addressee user had read the message:

   ```
   QB.chat.onReadStatusListener = updateReadersList;
   ```

And then add such a function with this signature:

```
function updateReadersList(messageId, dialogId, userId){
    console.log('userId has read your messageId that in dialogId');

}
```

**OPTION B:**

1. Add QB listener to handle new incoming messages:

   ```
   QB.chat.onMessageListener = showMessage;
   ```
2. Add such a listener function with this signature:
   In that listener you can notify the sender that his message was recived an d read (by you):

   ```
   function showMessage(userId, msg) {
   console.log('userId sent you this msg');

       //notify sender: message was read:
       if(userId != "MY-USER") {
         sendReadSignalToSender(msg, userId);
         console.log("You notified userId that his msg was read.");
       }
   ```

   }
3. Adding a simple function for just passing params to QB.chat.sendReadStatus function:

   ```
   function sendReadSignalToSender(dialogMsg, senderId){
   var params = {
     messageId: (dialogMsg.id || dialogMsg._id),
     userId: senderId,
     dialogId: (dialogMsg.dialog_id || dialogMsg.chat_dialog_id)
   };
   QB.chat.sendReadStatus(params);

   console.log("senderId was notified that his dialogMsg was read.");
   }
   ```